# Can't generate authentication code to login to Heroku Account

Tags: heroku, single-sign-on, multi-factor-authentication

I stupidly deleted my Authenticator app on my mobile phone and now I am unable to login to my Heroku account.  Is there any way round this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

If you have Multi-Factor Authentication, recovery codes can get you out of lock out.

If you do not have those, the only way is to reach out to Heroku Support(via : support@heroku.com). They'll ask some questions to verify your identity, and provide a single recovery code.

Refer to this [link](https://help.heroku.com/7IDU8QZZ/what-should-i-do-if-i-m-locked-out-of-my-heroku-account) for more details.

Comment: That link to Heroku Support goes to https://id.heroku.com/login requiring login. Help page also requires login. (Presumably a change since your reply).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, it was a mailto link, which had been turned into an http one.

Answer (score 0):

Help pages and web support require a login(!), so if you can't login you'll need to send [email](https://www.heroku.com/policy/support#:%7E:text=previously%20opened%20tickets.-,Email,to%20support%40heroku.com.) to support@heroku.com